# Expressing functions $n\to n$ as evaluation of polynomials mod $n$

Tags: group-theory, functions, prime-numbers

Consider $f:n\to n$ where $n:=\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$. We can associate to $f$ a polynomial $P_f$ of degree $<n$ by defining $P_f(x)=f(0)x^0+f(1)x^1+\cdots +f(n-1)x^{n-1}$. This gives another way to evaluate $f$: we have the literal function evaluation $x\mapsto f(x)$, and the "fancy" evaluation $x\mapsto \sum_{k<n}f(k)x^k$. I wish to understand a connection between these two evaluations.

**Question:** For $f:n\to n$, is there some polynomial $P(x)$  which evaluates to $P(x)\equiv f(x)$ (mod $n$) for all $x\in \mathbb{N}$?

**What I've done:** Assuming $n$ is prime, we only need to consider polynomials of degree $<n$ since by Fermat's Little Theorem $x^n\equiv x$. My idea was to find polynomials $i_k(x)$ which evaluate to the indicator function of the singleton $\{k\}$ so that $i_k(x)\equiv \begin{cases}1&x=k\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}$

Once we have these, every function can be written as a linear combination of the $i_k$ by $\left(\sum_{k<n}f(k)\cdot i_k\right)(x)\equiv f(x)$. To find these $i_k$, I used linear algebra to go in reverse. We start with the $n\times n $ matrix of the powers of $k<n$ reduced mod $n$. That is, $A_{i,j}=i^j$. For example, for $n=3$ this matrix is $A_3:=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&1\\1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$. For $n=4$, we have $A_4:=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\1&1&1&1\\1&2&0&0\\1&-1&1&-1\end{bmatrix}$ and for $n=5$ it is $A_5:=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\\1&1&1&1&1\\1&2&-1&-2&1\\1&-2&-1&2&1\\1&-1&1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$.

If the inverse of $A_n$ exists, it gives us the conversion matrix. In the case $n=3$ we have $A_3^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&1\\-1&-1&-1\end{bmatrix}$. Consider for example the function $0\mapsto 1,1\mapsto 2, 2\mapsto 0$. We compute $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&1\\-1&-1&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}\equiv\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ so our desired polynomial is $x^0+x^1$. Indeed, this evaluates correctly mod 3.

For $n$ prime, this matrix seems to always be invertible (at least up to 11 according to wolfram). Moreover, the leftmost column of the inverse matrix is always $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\\vdots\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ so the indicator $i_0(x)$ is the polynomial $1-x^{p-1}$. This corresponds to the corollary of Fermat's Theorem that $p\not\mid x\Rightarrow x^{p-1}\equiv 1$. Also, the bottom row of the inverse matrix always seems to be $\begin{bmatrix}-1&-1&\cdots&-1&-1\end{bmatrix}$. I have not been able to prove that $A_p$ is always invertible for $p$ prime.

For $n$ composite the $A_n$ seems never to be invertible, though I haven't been able to prove this either. However a proof of this wouldn't even answer the original question. Fermat's Theorem doesn't hold for composites, so we might theoretically find a suitable polynomial of degree $\geq n$.

I am also wondering about potential applications of this idea. If the symmetric group $S_p$ can be represented using polynomials in this way, group multiplication would correspond to composition of the polynomials (mod $p$). For example, we would have that $S_3\cong \{x,x+1,x+2,2x,2x+1,2x+2\}$. We don't typically think of $S_3$ as being linear polynomials (mod 3) under composition, but apparently (up to isomorphism) it is ! We could take this idea even further: for every $n$, there's always a least prime $p\geq n$ so we could potentially pick an embedding $S_n\leq S_p$. Then by Cayley's Theorem we could represent any finite group as composing polynomials (mod $p$) for some prime. Perhaps representing groups  this way would give new insights into group theory? I would also appreciate any other ideas for potential applications. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. First, note that

$$(x+n)^r=\sum_{k=0}^r\binom{r}{k}x^{r-k}n^k=x^r+\sum_{k=1}^r\binom{r}{k}x^{r-k}n^r\equiv x^r\ (\text{mod }n)$$

This then implies that for any polynomial, we have that

$$P(x+n)=\sum_{i=0}^r a_i(x+n)^i\equiv \sum_{i=0}^r a_ix^i=P(x)\ (\text{mod }n)$$

Thus, it is sufficient to find $P(x)$ such that

$$P(x)\equiv f(x)\ (\text{mod }n)$$

for $x\in \{0,1,...,n-1\}$. But the problem becomes trivial at this point. We simply need to find the interpolating polynomial such that

$$P(0)=f(0)$$

$$P(1)=f(1)$$

$$\vdots$$

$$P(n-1)=f(n-1)$$

This is a well known problem and algorithms to find such a $P(x)$ can be found in many places (for example [here](https://math.okstate.edu/people/binegar/4513-F98/4513-l17.pdf)).