# If $a_n$ is periodic, show this version $b_n$ with different terms for odd and even indices is periodic too.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, periodic-functions

Let $a_n = a_1,a_2,a_3,...$ be a periodic sequence and $T$ be its period.

Then the sequence $b_n$ with $b_{2n-1} = a_{(2m+2(n-1)+1)^2+2m+4(n-1)+3}$ for $n = 1,2,3,...$ and $b_{2n} = a_{(2m+2(n-1)+1)^2+6m+4(n-1)+4}$ for $n = 1,2,3,...$ and some fixed $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ should also be periodic with a period of $2T$, right?

Comment: It will be periodic but the period need not be $2T$. Consider the sequence $a_n=1$

Comment: Oh, thank you. But how would you show that $b_n$ is periodic too if $a_n$ is periodic in the first place?

Comment: Try to show that $P(n+T)\equiv P(n)\ (\text{mod }T)$ for any polynomial $P(x)$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully get what you mean by $n$. And is there a theorem to use or just some basic modular arithmetic?

Comment: Just basic modular arithmetic. See the start of this answer for the finer details https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4032171/364346

Comment: Right, since the index in both subcases is some polynomial P(n), you can conclude that there is some periodicity $T$ which can be proven by modular arithmetic and the binomial theorem as you showed. But $T$ may differ from the periodicity of $a_n$, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143228/discussion-between-qc-qaoa-and-spectre42).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have since asked another question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4649032/how-to-show-that-if-a-n-is-periodic-so-is-every-variation-b-pn-of-it-wi) (after several days of trying to solving the same problem) I'll answer your original question in full ot present a full picture for anyone who may have a similar question:

First, note that for any $T$ we have

$$(x+T)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}T^k= x^n+\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}T^k$$

$$=x^n+T\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}T^{k-1}\equiv x^n\ (\text{mod }T)$$

Then any polynomial $P(x)$ has the property

$$P(x+T)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x+T)^k\equiv \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k=P(x)\ (\text{mod }T)$$

Now, suppose that $a_n$ is periodic with some period $T$ and consider the sequence $r_n=a_{P(n)}$. We have that

$$r_{n+T}=a_{P(n+T)}=a_{P(n)+qT}=a_{P(n)}=r_n$$

which implies that $r(n)$ has **a** period of $T$ (not neccessarily a minimum period of $T$). The key step here is noticing that $P(n+T)=P(n)+qT$ for some integer $q$. Taking your specific question, we have shown that both $b_{2n}$ and $b_{2n-1}$ are both periodic with **a** (not necessarily the minimum) period of $T$. But then for even $n=2k$ and odd $n=2k-1$ respectively

$$b_{n+2T}=b_{2k+2T}=b_{2(k+T)}=b_{2k}=b_n$$

$$b_{n+2T}=b_{2k-1+2T}=b_{2(k+T)-1}=b_{2k-1}=b_n$$

We conclude that $b_n$ has **a** period of $2T$ although again we stress that this may not be the minimum period.